# Virtual Host who is serving 0.0.0.0:80?

Tags: nginx, virtual-machines, docker

I have a mac development box that has used virtualbox, homestead and docker. I am having issues with the newest docker, so I thought I would clean up unused machines.

I believe I have all virtual boxes off, including the newest docker mac, and all containers removed.

I am still seeing the default nginx page "It Works" at 0.0.0.0:80

How do I figure out who is serving this page?

Comment: On a linux system, it would be `sudo netstat -lntp` (sudo is required). Not sure if OSX includes that.

Comment: I modified the command to sudo netstat -lntp tcp which gives me a table.... in there i see an entry 127.0.0.1.1023 to 127.0.0.1:49153 as well as more regular internet... but not sure where to go from here, is that the traffic to 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: It's not clear to me where you're seeing the 0.0.0.0 traffic, are you actually trying to connect a browser to that? Because that address is designed for listeners on the server side, not for connecting from the client/browser side. It means "listen on every network interface"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
lsof -i | grep 80
```

It will show you what command/process owns what open sockets.

Comment: Works, does not show anything for 0.0.0.0:80 or localhost or something similar

Comment: Ok, try "sudo lsof -i" and look through each of the responses. It might render listening on port 80 as "*:http".